# How to improve nested object arrays lookup

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a common known way to chain .map or .filter or .find expressions to accomplish this kind of lookup?

Given and array of objects within an array of objects

```
customerGroups : 
[
   {
    id: 1,
    customers: [{
        id: 1, // The same customer may appear in multiple groups
        name: 'Jhon'
    }],
   },
   {
    id: 2,
    customers: [{
        id: 2, 
        name: 'Jhon'
    }],
   },
   {
    id: 3,
    customers: [{
        id: 2, 
        name: 'Doe'
    }],
   },
]
```

In the use case where you have the customer.id and want to find out the customer.name I would like to extract the customers array to use the Array.Find method

```
const idSearch = 1
const customerName = customers.find(({id})=>id==idSearch).name
```

So far I been trying with

```
const customers = customerGroup.find(({ customer }) =>
    customer.find(({ id }) =>idSearch === id),
  )?.customers
const customerName = customers.find(({id})=>id==idSearch).name
```

I believe there is a better way to do this but I'm too burnout to figure it out.

I've also tried some shenanigans with the .map to make a new array with all the customers in it but no good results so far.

I could also fetch that array from my Backend but I already have all the customers in memory so that would be an overheat.

Comment: Not in native JavaScript. You may be able to simplify it using a library like underscore.js.

Comment: `.flatMap()` may be helpful, though.

Comment: Could it be that the provided customer objects are misleading? Shouldn't a customer `id`/`name` pair be always unique (hence `id`)? Thus there should be one `{ id: 1, name: 'Jhon' }` within the customer group of `id: 1`, and there should be the same unique `{ id: 2, name: 'Doe' }` object each within the customer groups of `id: 2` and `id: 3`.

Comment: there is a better way to do this, but it requires changing how the data is stored. `customerGroups`, rather than being an array, should be an object where the ids are keys. Then you could look up directly by id rather than having to use `.find` (that part would be O(1) rather than O(n) where `n` is the number of customer groups).

Comment: Seems like I just stepped on a land mine. 
I could do what @RobinZigmond proposed at the time I store the data on my state management. But for now, I'll accept the .flatmap() answer and get back to work. Thank you all, you've been really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not one native method that does this, but you could first combine the `customer` arrays into one with `flatMap`, and then use `find`:

```js
const customerGroups = [{id:1,customers:[{id:1,name:'Jhon'}]},{id:2,customers:[{id:2,name:'Jhon'}]},{id:3,customers:[{id:2,name: 'Doe'}]}];
const idSearch = 1;

const allCustomers = customerGroups.flatMap(({customers}) => customers);
const name = allCustomers.find(({id}) => id === idSearch)?.name;

console.log(name);
```

Comment: Btw there is a `Cannot destructure property` error if no match is found

Comment: Should not happen after the update made.

Answer (score 1):

This approach works because as soon as the inside find loop discovers a result, both the inside and outside loop will terminate, leaving `name` set as the match which caused the loops to terminate (or as undefined if no match was found).

```js
const d = [{id:1,customers:[{id:1,name:'Jhon'}]},{id:2,customers:[{id:2,name:'Jhon'}]},{id:3,customers:[{id:3,name: 'Doe'}]}]
const idSearch = 1

let name
d.find(j=>j.customers.find(i=>i.id===idSearch && ({name}=i)))

console.log(name)
```